# Different git pager options for diff and show

Tags: git, git-diff, git-config, git-show

I like my tabs displayed as 4 spaces, and for that I have the preference `core.pager = 'less -x4'`.

I know that at this point I'm nitpicking, but I'd love for the leading tab to be 4 spaces even in diff mode, which is obviously the most commonly used -- however it displays as only 3 due to the leading `+`, `-`, or . This is slightly annoying due to aligned lines, if some have no leading tabs they are shifted by 1 column compared to the others.

I can correct the display for diffs with `less -x1,5` to get 4-space tabs, aligned on the column 1 modulo 4. However this option then causes the leading tab to be displayed as 1 column in non-diff mode, which in turn is highly disturbing.

So for two concrete examples, how can I set git options such that I use:

- `less -x1,5` for a diff (or really patch-displaying) command such as `git diff` or `git show HEAD`
- `less -x4` for a command that does not display a diff such as `git show HEAD~1:package.json`

I'm sure there has to be a different renderer for what are basically `diff` and `cat` operations, but I haven't been able to find specific options for those (though they might exist, there's a lot of noise on git topics). I don't want to write a whole lot of aliases either, that's a little too dirty. So is this even possible?

Comment: The usual approach to solve this is to avoid hard-tabs at all: set your editor to use 4-space "soft" tabs, type the tab key, and you get spaces that everyone agrees how to format. That's the best answer I've ever found to the constant tab-vs-space war, even if it's not all that satisfactory.

Comment: @torek Well git has some tab-whitespace awareness, I was hoping maybe it could do the tab expansion using the [whitespace.tabwidth](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corewhitespace) option or some trick like that. After all it already does the colouring of the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`pager.<cmd>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pagerltcmdgt) allows to set pager for a command:

```
git config [--global] pager.diff "less -x1,5"
git config [--global] pager.show "less -x4"
```

Comment: That's pretty good, especially for such an easy solution. Ideally I would have liked for some `show` commands to behave differently, based on whether they show a patch or a file.

Comment: @Cimbali: you can't quite get that, unfortunately. You could make yourself an alias, `git showfile` or some such, that runs `!git --config pager.show=<settings> show`.